# Probability of product x*y with ln(0) in integral

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two random variables with the following distributions:

- P(x) = 2(1-x), 0 < x < 1
- P(y) = 1, 0 < y < 1

I want to find the pdf $P(x\cdot y = z)$. Here is how I'm doing it:
$$
\int_0^1 P_y(y)P_x(z/y)\frac{1}{|y|}dx \\
2\int_0^1 1/y - z/y^2dy = 2[ln(y)+z/y]_0^1
$$
but ln(0) is indetermined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is easier with CDFs:  To get $XY\le z$ then either $0 \le X\le z$ with any $Y$ or, when $z \le X \le 1$, then $0 \le Y \le \frac{z}{X}$.  That suggests to me that at least your limits may need adjustment

Comment: Thanks, Aaron, I just updated the question. I want to find the pdf $P(x\cdot y = z)$.

Comment: Thanks, Henry. I'll take a crack at that.

Comment: Notice $P_x (\frac{z}{y})=0$ if  $\frac{z}{y} \geq 1$. In other words: $y$ must be greater than $z$ for $z>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z=XY$, then indeed the density of $Z$ is given by
$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{\mathbb R}f_X(x)f_Y(z/x)\frac1{|x|}\ \mathsf dx.
$$
Here $f_X(x)=2(1-x)\cdot \mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(x)$ and $f_Y(y)= \mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(y)$. The relation $\frac zx\in(0,1)$ occurs precisely when $0<z<x$, and hence
$$
f_Z(z) = \int_z^1 \frac{2(1-x)}x\ \mathsf dx = 2(z-(1+\log z)),\quad z\in(0,1).
$$